# Generic records enforce at least one property

Tags: typescript

Here's the declaration of my function (simplified as much as possible):

```
type A<T extends Record<string, string>> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] // Simplified, should stay
} & {
  title: string
}

function example<B extends Record<string, string>>(a: A<B>, b?: B) {}
```

Everything works fine when I pass both `a` and `b`, since I can't pass unknown keys to the `a`:

```
example(
  // B infers as `{ anythingHere: string; }`
  {
    title: 'with b',
    // @ts-expect-error
    unknownKey: 'fails as expected',
  },
  {
    anythingHere: 'anythingHere',
  },
)
```

However, when I don't provide the `b` parameter, I actually can pass anything to the `a`, which is wrong:

```
example({
  // B infers as `{ title: string; unknownKey: "not failing"; }`
  title: 'without b',
  unknownKey: 'doesn\'t fail but should',
})
```

I understand that the problem is in the `Record<string, string>` and the type widening, but I can't figure out how to resolve it.

The code above is a simplified version of this one:

```
const Button = classed('button', {
  props: {
    type: 'button', // ok, inferred from the `ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'button'>`
    className: 'btn', // also ok
    UNKNOWN_KEY: '11111' // should raise an error
  },
  // variants: {}  <-- not defined
})
```

The real-world use case can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgawgJQnAxsAQgV2MAewDsAFAJwLAGcoBeKAbwCgopRIB%20ALigHIAjPISK8oAHz5Uc-ALYBLYKIm8yEKhEUso6ADZwqVAHJwZEblCrAycogHNxUHEQAmEAGY2IzpgF8mTdmgANThrOCJgGnpUdAIyZwAeS2s7ABooAEEyMjgQBKcEIgIAdyIAPjL-QKgQsIjySioE2rlwyIAVKAgAD2AIFxoWtqoyukYtAG0SKBsoJBACNxrQ1oiqdoBdcyG19qmNiaIcGX4IMg3fKvBoAGE9Ay8G6gStHY6u3v7nQZXh1KZRvR4EhUBhsEJiE8aAAyZZ1YBQ5q-XaVJhuJyYOTEbT3dSJLQAUR0EFMEXa106PT6AwsVhstn%20rFiREscNW7ypXx%208Ko-zKAAotBBiaTgOTIDwiST%20mKKYzxqxWGAKNR5awAG7IyLynw8ZiKqDKxrmO76PGIt7rSoGzU87Za9ZaHxjBg%20f4ASkYfiYzNZuHwxAAjGNdGavPyBBCROl9YaVVQ9VpWIEeLwpLIFLw1RY5AAvCCpnS2LNJqAASUMQQyABkywARAD6AGkCQBNVNuOByHQ0fQfSCYLwl1hurS29kJhWKsFYog8Ca8ZVyGShEBZyQQZnOVfr3h9MjAVpkNcbbNUPMFqALqgyXcyZy7ou8U9O-4%20d3%20X3AKD%204QAJhDXFw0jANoynI1qETA0U0kaR5EUbMKyrWtGxbds%20GcAg1CIAAdPcoE7bsoEEb8qAACwIHAdAfHU3w-IA).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggPAFQHxQLxQN4CgpQNoAKUAlgHZQDWEIA9gGZQIC6AXI4UwNxYC+UAZJhxRgxYABsIbAM7AATmQDm3Htyx0ArqQDGomuQgAPAIYBbMJLgAhJAApjbeFahHgEUgBNpULR4h0yCA8oAH4oACUIbRo5DzhZBVJFABooUggANwg5FDYbVIAjELyASkweLCwjMwsIW2FsXFxRCSkoACIAdzEACygC9uThXC0KUhpO0gBpajZ2umNicW9jbyNIXSDBqAB6HagFpelhHiHcRqbjUhBgHqUACWy29qubu6THuQhBk6GStWq5kktguLUkc26txoGmA-R+I1IYwm01mHUOyygqxchg2bg82z2mOWNAOi2WvH+WCAA) with adjusted generic constraints work for you?

Comment: @Behemoth, thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, even though your solution solves the example above, I couldn't fit it into the real-world code. I now realize that I have to provide full declaration. Please see question's update because the URL is too long for the comment.